# basic authentication/identities and aspnet core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to use basic authentication in ASP.NET core. I found in the Security repository on GitHub (https://github.com/aspnet/security) that it is not going to be implemented. Is there anything else that can be used in place of it? I looked at bearer tokens, but from what I could see is that they are basically another way in using OAuth from Facebook/Twitter/etc.

I am using this on a web api controller/action on the backend service and want to verify what product is communicating with the backend along with specific settings for that site stored in a database. I don't/can't use any 3rd party system (Facebook/Twitter/Etc) and I'm really trying to keep this simple and not ridiculously complex with running a separate OAuth system. One of the recommended basic auth solutions in the github repo isn't around anymore and the other only reads users/credentials from the config file. I've tried modifying the code in the config only example to read the data from the identity stores, but the "Authorize" attributes keep failing because Basic isn't recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ASP.NET Core Identity with Entity Framework Core**

If you are using ASP.NET Core Identity with Entity Framework Core, you should be able to use simple Cookie Authentication by following the instructions from https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/index.html.

Its magic actually came from [`app.UseIdentity()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/BuilderExtensions.cs).

---

**JWT Bearer Authentication (Bearer Token)** ([previously OAuthBearer](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/87))

Since you are asking for bearer token and I guess `CookieAuthentication` might not be the best way for your API backend, please take a look to ASP.NET Security JWT Bearer. It will validate the JWT passed in header while you will have to implement the token issuance by yourself.

[**Sources**](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer)

[**Samples**](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/samples/JwtBearerSample)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to implement something pretty easily with the JWT Bearer authentication. Here's my post on it. http://www.frakkingsweet.com/my-blog/plain-and-simple-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core